# Magento site switching .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento

I'm been trying for several hours to get a different store to display based on a subdirectory. Our staging site set up for Magento is for a Rest of the World, US, UK and Australian stores with various differences between them. We have had these working by set environmental variables in the .htaccess (I'll use the base and Australian store only for brevity), which are then used in the index.php file to load the correct store.

```
SetEnvIf Host staging\.hostname\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=base
SetEnvIf Host staging\.hostname\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store

SetEnvIf Host staging-au\.hostname\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=au
SetEnvIf Host staging-au\.hostname\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

I've now been tasked with changing this to use subdirectories, so staging.hostname.com/au/ , and whatever I put in doesn't work.

I've changed the base url for the different stores in the configuration to point at staging.hostname.com/au/ for the Australian store. From what I can see it's not picking up my new .htaccess lines of

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/au/.*" MAGE_RUN_CODE=au
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/au/.*" MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

I've tried the regular expression with and without quotation marks, and with and without the wildcard anything (.*) and no joy.

I did ensure to delete / Comment out the SetEnvIf Host lines as well, as otherwise it would probably be causing problems as I'd set the environmental variable twice.

If I leave the old url pointing at the store (staging-au.hostname.com) then Magento redirects to the store's base URL of staging.hostname.com/au (so that means the old .htaccess information works), but then it defaults back to the base store values and gives me a 404 error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Apache version 2.2.21 if that helps.

Comment: make your life easier : http://blog.speedupmate.com/post/9992573819/poor-mans-multisite-setup-for-magento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend how you've set up US, UK etc. Assuming they are set-up as stores you should simply be able to enable System > Configuration > Web > URL Options > Add Store Code to Urls, and not have to mess around with your request_uri via .htaccess.

Comment: If we'd set things up correctly, this is what we should have done. As this was a last minute change to everything that had already happened it was too late.

And now we've gone with using subdomains :)

Answer (score 3):

On some servers the SetEnvIf directive does not get recognized in the .htaccess file.

Environment variables also act a little funny when dealing with redirects in .htaccess, especially when you have redirects in .htaccess files that run in sub-directories.

Apache will actually rename the environment variable by adding "REDIRECT_" in front of it.

To get it to work like you want, remove the SetEnvIf directives and add the following just below "#RewriteBase /magento/" in Magento's root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/au/.* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/au$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:au]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_CODE} (.+)
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:%1,E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just not bother with having explicit store codes at all. If you use GEOIP to get the two letter country code in your index.php you can the have a simple switch/case/if construct to set the store code variable or website code and then call the main program. If you do it that way then you don't have to have store codes in the URL.

```
$country=$_SERVER['GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE'];
//if (isset($_COOKIE['geocountry'])) $country=$_COOKIE['geocountry'];

switch ($country)
{ case "CA": case "MX": case "US":
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] = "usd";
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] = "website";
break;
  case "AT": case "BE": case "CY": case "DE": case "ES": case "FI": case "FR": case "GR": case "IE": case "IT": case "LU": case "MT": case "NL": case "SI":
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] = "eur";
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] = "website";
break;
  case "BG": case "CZ": case "DK": case "EE": case "HU": case "LV": case "PL": case "RO": case "SE":
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] = "eugbp";
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] = "store";
break;
  case "GB":
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] = "gbp";
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] = "website";
break;
  case "AX":
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] = "staging";
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] = "store";
break;
  default:
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] = "row";
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] = "store";
}
```

Note you will need a cookie/ip address or other mechanism to over-ride the geo-ip for testing purposes. You won't need different URLs for the different stores or any different sub directories. You will still be able to theme up each store differently and have different currencies at the website level.

Comment: This is basically what the GeoIP extension is already doing. But your answer made me realise I was in the whitelist of sites not affected by it ... so I think that was half the issue I was having. Thanks.