# Magento Multi Store URL rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting

We are working on a Magento site that has several different stores. We are working on rewriting the url so when you are in a specific store, the store name is added to the url. We have tried a couple of different things. First by turning on "Add Store Code to Urls" in System>Configuration>Web. This causes one of the store names to be added to the url twice and the rest of the stores the base store name is added. Our second idea was to add:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^\/site_wow\/ MAGE_RUN_CODE=site_wow
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^\/site_ahepa\/ MAGE_RUN_CODE=site_ahepa
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^\/site_ita\/ MAGE_RUN_CODE=site_ita
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^\/site_deca\/ MAGE_RUN_CODE=site_deca
```

to the .htaccess file in the public_html folder on the site. This works for the ahepa store but none of the others. If I change the other stores to MAGE_RUN_CODE=site_ahepa, it adds the site_ahepa to the url.

I found a similar question here: [Magento site switching .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754089/magento-site-switching-htaccess) but am not having any luck fixing the problem. If there is anyone who could send me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is what I got to work. I have the .htaccess file as it is above. In System>Configuration>Web, I have Add Store Code to Urls set to YES and Use Web Server Rewrites set to NO. The url rewrite for the ahepa store is different that the other stores but all of the links redirect to the correct stores and the products are showing up where they are supposed to so I am not going to mess with it anymore.

Comment: I did as you said but I the css is not loading properly in the two stores. Any ideas?

Comment: No not really. This was the only time I did anything with Magento. We were helping another company in the building with the site and their customer decided they didn't like Magento so they pulled the plug on the project.