# Magento Multiple stores in 1.7 version

Tags: php, magento

I have upgraded my magento store form 1.6.2 to 1.7.0.2. I want to manage one more store form that same admin. I checked the related steps but 2nd store url giving the same layout and design as that of first. I made a folder for 2nd store and added a .htasccess and index .php files. Any body knows the proper steps to follow? please help..

Thanks....

Comment: Have you configured the second stores URL settings? Admin -> Configuration -> General -> Web. Then select the second store from the dropdown in top left.

Comment: yes i changed the url settings and selected the second store from left top drop down. But shows no effect

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this in your each .htaccess file

.htacess 1

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^\/site_wow\/ MAGE_RUN_CODE=site_wow
```

.htacess 2

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^\/site_ahepa\/ MAGE_RUN_CODE=site_ahepa
```

Read more @ [Magento Multi Store URL rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459835/magento-multi-store-url-rewrite)

You may also want to read http://www.crucialwebhost.com/blog/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/

Also you should be able to run both site from the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working on my install as follows (using Magento CE 1.7.0.2):

1. staging.domain.com -> default UK store -> English store view
2. staging.domain.eu -> default EU store -> French store view

Setting the System -> Configuration -> General -> Web variables **base URL** for both **secure** and **unsecure** to either *staging.domain.com* or *staging.domain.eu*, respectively.

Then I added this to my .htaccess file for EACH domain:

```
SetEnvIf Host staging\.domain\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain_uk
SetEnvIf Host staging\.domain\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain_uk
SetEnvIf Host ^domain\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

Hope that helps. Full tut here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup