# Magento - Multi store rewrite - url change

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I have a Magento website that is running in production environment for a year now.

Now we want to create a Wholesale and retail store in this same installation. We are did that in a test environment and everything works fine.

So, before multistore created, we had our URL example.com.

Now, we are using different websites, setting "Add Store Code to Urls" to YES, so we have:

Retail: example.com/default
Wholesale: example.com/wholesale

However, my URL's will be "broken" when someone search for it on Google. Is there a way to set up when someone try to access a URL without store code, to add the "default" code (for retail store)?

Comment: just check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459835/magento-multi-store-url-rewrite

Comment: thank you @Julian, before I post here I've checked this link, but it is a little different from my problem, but I changed the way we were working (we're using store code to URL and now I'm using subdomains with htaccess rules).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may solve this using .htaccess / virtual hosts combined with magento run code. There are many resources with in depth articles (like [the first google result I got](https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/30/How-To-Setup-Magento-With-Multiple-Stores-And-Domains)).

Comment: Thank you @abstraction! We were using store code added to URL, but I think it's not so usual. I searched here and on Google but I couldnt solve the problem with store code. So we changed to use it with a subdomain. Now it is working and we keep our URL's untouched (to retail version).